# Arrows indicating parallel sides on a trapezium

Tags: arrows, parallel

I have the following code to draw a trapezium.

I wish to have arrows, indicating that one of the pairs of opposites sides are parallel.
how do get the arrows onto parallel sides?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node [trapezium, trapezium right angle=45,trapezium left angle=75, 
       minimum size=30mm,draw,thick, label=above:7cm, label=below:16cm, 
       label=right:9cm, label=left:8cm] at (0,0){};
  \draw [black,thick,dashed] (1.7,1.5) --(5,1.5);
  \draw [black,thick,dashed,->] (4.7,-1.5) --(4.7,1.5);
  \node [right] at (4.7,0) {4 m};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In future, rather than posting code snippets can you please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would draw the trapezium "by hand". Assuming that the `4m` distance is supposed to be `4cm`, the right-hand angle in the trapezium cannot be as given in the OP and, instead, the diagram should look more like:

[image]

[Of course, now the 9cm is clearly wrong. The real distance is closer to `4.5cm`.]

I have used the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for the units and the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `decorations.markings` library to define a new arrow style `->-` that puts the arrow in the middle of the line. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric,}
\begin{document}

  \tikzset{%
    ->-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                postaction={decorate}}
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[dotted/.style={black,dashed}, trapezium/.style={thick}]
    \draw[trapezium,->-](0,0) --node[below]{\si{16}{cm}}++(16,0);
    \draw[trapezium](0,0)--node[left=2mm]{\si{8}{cm}}(7,4);
    \draw[trapezium][->-](7,4) --node[above]{\si{7}{cm}}++(7,0);
    \draw[trapezium](16,0)--node[right]{\si{9}{cm}}(14,4);
    \draw[dotted](14,4)--++(2.3,0);
    \draw[dotted,->] (16,0) --node[right]{\si{4}{cm}}++(0,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Finally, I also dropped the `thick` from the dotted lines because I think they should have less emphasis than the lines making up the trapezium.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nodes provided by the `shapes.geometric` library to draw a marked path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node [trapezium, trapezium right angle=45,trapezium left angle=75, 
       minimum size=30mm,draw,thick, label=above:7cm, label=below:16cm, 
       label=right:9cm, label=left:8cm] (trapezium) at (0,0){};
  \draw [black,thick,dashed] (1.7,1.5) --(5,1.5);
  \draw [black,thick,dashed,->] (4.7,-1.5) --(4.7,1.5);
  \node [right] at (4.7,0) {4 m};
  \path[postaction={decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex}}},decorate}] 
            ([yshift=-\pgflinewidth]trapezium.top left corner) -- ([yshift=-\pgflinewidth]trapezium.top right corner);
  \path[postaction={decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex}}},decorate}] 
            ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]trapezium.bottom left corner) -- ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]trapezium.bottom right corner);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One subtlety here is that one has to shift by the line width in order to get the arrows really on top.